# Отследить размер элемента javascript

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как отследить размер элемента в реальном времени без jquery?

Например есть div1 и есть div2 и я хочу передать второму какую-то часть ширины первого в реальном времени, грубо говоря изменяю первый - изменяется и второй.

Comment: Не уверен, но "getcomputedstyle" погуглите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ширину элемента можно получить с помощью [window.getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle). Для IE8 можно использовать `element.clientWidth` или `.offsetWidth`. Первое свойство также включает в себя `padding`, второе — `padding`, `border` и ширину полосы прокрутки.

Далее, чтобы отследить изменения, в новых браузерах можно использовать [Mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). В IE до 11й версии — onpropertychange. Код отслеживания изменений:

```
function listenerCreate(src, dst){
    function changeWidth(){
        var newWidth=getDivWidth(src);
        if(src.oldWidth!=newWidth){
            dst.style.width=src.oldWidth=newWidth;
        }
    }
    src.oldWidth=getDivWidth(src);
    if(typeof(MutationObserver) !== 'undefined'){
        var MO=new MutationObserver(changeWidth);
        MO.observe(src, {
            attributes: true,
            childList: true,
            characterData: true
        });
    } else {
        src.onpropertychange = changeWidth;
    }
}
```

Пример полностью — на [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ExH8Z/2/). Кстати, любопытный баг: получить CSS-свойство с помощью getComputedStyle из функции на этом сайте можно, лишь добавив к нему пустую строку. Наверное, это как-то связано с фреймами.

Comment: Сейчас буду разбираться, честно признаться удивлен таким громоздким кодом, насколько же с jquery проще работать.

Comment: @kils а вы правда думали что jQuery написали от нечего делать ?